# Откуда же взялся скролл?

Tags: css, прокрутка

Всем привет!
Я установил абсолютные значения для основных блоков, но прокрутка все равно не исчезает.

Почему погрешность 9px?

Почему, когда я удаляю свойство блока `blue` justify-content: space-between; или добавляю padding-bottom: 9px; для блока `red` прокрутка исчезает?

https://jsfiddle.net/81u0jxqr/

Comment: Может вы хоть что-то приложите, например html и css, чтоб хотя бы что-то можно было сказать по этому поводу?

Comment: Нам нужно немного кода :(

Comment: прошу прощенья, тупанул от усталости https://jsfiddle.net/81u0jxqr/

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен. Во первых, если убрать у класса `blue` свойство `justify-content: space-between;`, то скролл по прежнему будет, просто он будет меньше. А вот если убрать `height: 100%` , для `.blue`, тогда скролл действительно пропадет.
И наконец решение с вопросом. Зачем вам межстрочный интервал в **180px**? Уберите его, и все станет как вы и ожидали.

Рабочий код -

```css
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    height: 60px;
    background: palevioletred;
    border-top: yellow 1px solid;
}
section{
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
.orange{
    background: darkorange;
    height: 100%;
}
.blue{
    background: steelblue;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.golden{
    background: palegoldenrod;
}
.red{
    background: indianred;
    font-size: 180px;
    /* line-height: 180px; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<section>
    <div class="orange">
        <div class="blue">
            <div class="golden">What's</div>
            <div class="red">wron</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS:** пожалуйста, задавайте вопрос более точно, прикладывайте код.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но скролл и правда исчезает на проде лишь при удалении `justify-content: space-between;`. Видимо, косяк jsfiddle
Если убрать  `height: 100%`  для `.blue` пропадет не только скролл)) 
Межстрочный интервал там необходим по макету. Просто хотелось бы более глубоко понимать спецификацию, а с помощью простого поиска динамику поведения скролла в данномконтексте я не нашел.

Comment: Ну, смотрит, предположим, что это "косяк" jsfiddle (Хотя, я честно скопировал ваш код к себе в айдишку, и пробовал там), но, при любом раскладе, вы занимаете 100% высоты экрана учитывая текст, а потом, вы даете этому тексту межстрочный  интервал слишком огромный (из за него, естественно и получается дополнительный отступ для текста, что в свою очередь приводит к скроллу), такой интервал ставят на заголовки, а они, зачастую однострочные

Comment: 100% для флекса не страшно, ведь shrink по умолчанию 0. Углубляясь в этот вопрос, я пришел к выводу, что виноват не столько line-height, сколько природа самого шрифта. Вот хорошая статья: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align Спасибо за беседу!

Comment: @АнтонАндреев Пожалуйста, надеюсь, был полезен